# C# Pulling MySQL Results into Array

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays

I want to pull something I query into an array.

```
SELECT * FROM `x`
```

There may be 1 result or 1,000 results. The columns will vary, I mean, I'd rather be vague than write a specific interpreter for each query, I'd rather the function determine the column names.

So what do I really want?

```
<?php
    $results = mysql::query("SELECT * FROM x");
    $holding = array();

    //Now we get the results.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) $holding[] = $row;
?>
```

Obviously this is not C#, but I'd like the equivalent. I want all of my results, retaining their column names, in an array so I can call holding[0]["Column"];

My C# code is as follows.

```
            if (connected)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read()){
                //The problem is here, I don't know how to add them to a list/array retaining column names etc..

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to get all rows into an array you can do so by using `Linq to DataTable`:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
```

Then you have an array of `DataRows`, you can get a value of a particular column using the indexer of `DataRow` for example:

```
// value of the id column of first row
var value = rows[0]["id"];
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Took a while to implement, as the return was from the method to push through to another method. Thanks!